# Open Source Simulator for FinFET

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, open-source, finfet

I tried using the PTM 14nm model file on LTSpice. I realized LTSpice does not support BSIM-CMG models. Is there any alternative like LTSpice, which can simulate FinFET models?
Thank you.

Comment: That model is probably part of a design kit (PDK) which will be verified by the company that supports that PDK (usually the Foundry) using certain versions of specific tools. Have you checked which simulator this model is supposed to be used with, there should be a list somewhere.

Comment: There are some FinFETs that work in LTspice, but need adjustments to various non-standard SPICE netlist commands. There are a few threads on that in the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/). Depending on what you need and the compromises you're wlling to accept, it might be worth it, it might not. Why did you add the [tag:ltspice] if you're looking for open source software?

Comment: ngspice implements BSIM-CMG, so it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

seems that https://github.com/Qucs/ADMS might can do it,

then you can try if ngspice or QUCS can use the result model.

Good luck :-)

but even development on the great QUCS seems to have stoped :-(

Answer (score 1):

ngspice-39 supports BSIM-CMG (and all other Verilog-A compact device models) via its OSDI interface and the OpenVAF Verilog-A compiler.